# Flex line chart data points

Tags: apache-flex, graph, flex3, adobe, linechart

I am always displaying the data points of a flex line chart using `itemRenderer` for `LineSeries`. The problem I am facing is, the first and the last datapoints are not clearly visible. Please find the attached image for further clarity.

[image: Flex LineChart datapoints problem]

How do I display the first and last datapoints completely?

Thanks,
Anji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the following should do the trick for you

1. Try reducing the 'radius' attribute of the LineSeries tag to something like value 3.

2.Using stylesheets, add  a padding/margin left and right for the series.

Try that and update how this works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I add padding for the series?

Comment: did you try the first solution? you can use the style tag, and write css for the series and add padding. Check http://flanture.blogspot.com/2008/05/flex-components-styling.html to check how to write css for flex

Comment: Yes i have tried the first solution. Still the problem persists.

Comment: another link for styling charts using css http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_formatting_02.html